# outer apply how to using select from joined table

Tags: t-sql

I have a stored procedure in which I cannot add GROUP BY. I need to somehow take the number of records from another table. From the back-end come filter parameters (samples) for one table from it, I want to get data on the number of records.

```
SELECT cei_mot_count.cnt FROM someTable AS st
 LEFT JOIN CEI_Motivations AS cei_mot ON cei_mot.Id= st.ID    
--LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Id, StayingID, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM CEI_Motivations GROUP BY Id,StayingID) as cei_mot_count ON cei_mot_count.StayingID = cei_mot.StayingID
--LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Id, COUNT(cei_mot.Id) as cnt FROM cei_mot GROUP BY Id) as cei_mot_count ON cei_mot_count.Id IS NOT NULL
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(mot.Id) as cnt     
                    FROM  cei_mot as mot 
             WHERE mot.Id IS NOT NULL                    
                    GROUP BY mot.Id) as cei_mot_count
```

i catch Exception: Invalid object name 'cei_mot'

Comment: Are you able to add example data and an expected output?

Comment: i need cei_mot_count.cnt

Comment: Then you already have a query that gives it. I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: i dont know why, but i catch  exception: Invalid object name 'cei_mot'

Comment: in original stored procedure more code

Comment: is there such table `cei_mot` in your database ? You reference to that table in your `OUTER APPLY` section

Comment: I thought he would take data with cei_mot

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a table alias from a join inside an apply. I think what you want is:

```
SELECT cei_mot_count.cnt FROM someTable AS st
 LEFT JOIN CEI_Motivations AS cei_mot ON cei_mot.Id= st.ID    
--LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Id, StayingID, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM CEI_Motivations GROUP BY Id,StayingID) as cei_mot_count ON cei_mot_count.StayingID = cei_mot.StayingID
--LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Id, COUNT(cei_mot.Id) as cnt FROM cei_mot GROUP BY Id) as cei_mot_count ON cei_mot_count.Id IS NOT NULL
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(mot.Id) as cnt     
                    FROM  CEI_Motivations as mot 
             WHERE mot.Id IS NOT NULL AND mot.Id= st.ID                    
                    GROUP BY mot.Id) as cei_mot_count
```

Note how this version uses CEI_Motivations twice independently.

Comment: i alwayse get count 1

Comment: are there any ways to use joined table as a table

Comment: All joins allow the joined table to be used as a table. If you get a count of 1 every time it means the ID you're joining on is unique within the table.

Comment: can i use cei_mot as a table and count the quantity?

Comment: cei_mot is an alias for the table CEI_Motivations.

Comment: how do I get to data in cei_mot?

Comment: Add the columns you need after SELECT in the query, you're basically asking how to write a simple SELECT statement in SQL as far as I understand. I don't think I can help further without sample data and an example of expected output.